# How to create or use operator at the end of pipeline although it write the beginning?

Tags: rxjs

I have a `subject` in rxjs. and I want to use `shareReplay` operator.

The problem is I can't add operators to the end of the pipeline, only at the beginning: (why? please lets assume this is the case for now and I can't change that)

```
const subject = new Subject();

const foo = subject.pipe(
   // only here I can add operators.
   .... // can't do nothing here.
   shareReplay // can't do that here.
);


const bar = subject.pipe(
   // only here I can add operators.
   .... // can't do nothing here.
   shareReplay // can't do that here.
);
```

So my question is can I create an operator that do `shareReplay` at the end of the pipeline when I write it at the begin of the pipeline? because rxjs is running the operators in the order they write. so I need operator or using shareReplay to work like I writing at the end of the pipeline:

```
const bar = subject.pipe(
   shareReplay(), // or myOperator()
   .... // can't do nothing here.
);
```

Comment: In general, of course no. This is absolutely not possible. I think you're trying to reify  a list in a new order, but to do that here means to remimagine composition. You can ad something to the end of the strean, but not the end of the composition...

Comment: It is kinda possible. May I ask what's the use case of this?

Comment: @FanCheung Yes. I want to provide `shareReplay` when user ask for subject. I want to give the user in my application subject with shareReplay then he will add his pipe logic. How to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a higher order function to achieve that

```
const withShareReplay=(observableChain)=>subject.pipe(...observableChain,shareReplay())
```

usage

```
withShareReplay([switchMap(...), tap(...)])
```